# Desplazarme con las flechas del teclado en los li que se generan apartir de la base de datos y seleccionarlo con enter

Tags: javascript, html, elixir

Tengo mi input que al escribir texto se renderan las opciones (ul li) de la base de datos que coinciden con las palabras clave que escribi, quiero saber como seleccionar el li con las flechas del teclado y con la tecla enter para que ese item sea el seleccionado ya que solo lo hace con el clic del mouse. Ya sea con javascript puro o html. Gracias.
Input:

```
<input class="form-control" id="InputArticulo" placeholder="Buscar artículo... :)" phx-list="list_items" phx-value="<%= @product %>" title="Campo de selección de artículo para agregar a la lista"
```

Lista:

```
<ul class="list-group">
      <%= for item <- @items do %>
        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action max-h-48 overflow-auto" phx-click="select_item" phx-value-item="<%= item.id %>" phx-value-name="SKU: <%= item.sku %>, Código: <%= item.value %> - <%= item.name %>">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <div id="itemName" class="flex-1">
              <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> <%= item.name %>
              <p class="mb-0">sku: <%= item.sku %>, código: <%= item.value %></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Lo que necesitas para hacer funcionar las teclas es:

- Solo debes tomar en cuenta las teclas cuando el campo de texto tenga el foco, para no interferir con otros elementos
- Agregar una clase CSS para saber qué elemento es el que está seleccionado
- Al presionar teclas Arriba o Abajo:

  - Eliminas la clase del elemento activo
  - Analizas el elemento activo para saber qué dirección tomar y seleccionar el siguiente
  - Agregas la clase al nuevo elemento seleccionado
- Al presionar la tecla Enter, solo verificas que hay un elemento activo y disparas el clic

Revisa los comentarios en el código.

```js
// Obtener la lista, para recorrer cada elemento
let listGroup = document.querySelector('ul.list-group');
// Asignar evento al campo de texto
document.querySelector('#inputArticulo').addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    if(!listGroup) {
        return; // No existe la lista
    }
    // Obtener todos los elementos
    let items = listGroup.querySelectorAll('li');
    // Saber si alguno está activo
    let actual = Array.from(items).findIndex(item => item.classList.contains('active'));
    // Analizar tecla pulsada
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        // Tecla Enter, evitar que se procese el formulario
        e.preventDefault();
        // ¿Hay un elemento activo?
        if(items[actual]) {
            // Hacer clic
            items[actual].click();
        }
    } if(e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40) {
        // Flecha arriba (restar) o abajo (sumar)
        if(items[actual]) {
            // Solo si hay un elemento activo, eliminar clase
            items[actual].classList.remove('active');
        }
        // Calcular posición del siguiente
        actual += (e.keyCode == 38) ? -1 : 1;
        // Asegurar que está dentro de los límites
        if(actual < 0) {
            actual = 0;
        } else if(actual >= items.length) {
            actual = items.length - 1;
        }
        // Asignar clase activa
        items[actual].classList.add('active');
    }
});
// En la función donde generas la lista debes activar evento clic para cada elemento
// Para este ejemplo se hace manual
listGroup.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(li => {
    li.addEventListener('click', e => {
        // Asignar valor al campo
        document.querySelector('#inputArticulo').value = e.currentTarget.textContent;
        // Aquí deberías cerrar la lista y/o eliminar el contenido
    });
});
```

```css
.list-group {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.list-group li {
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px #aaa solid;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
.list-group li.active {
    color: #008;
    background: #cef;
    border: 1px #008, solid;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputArticulo">
<ul class="list-group">
    <li>Elemento 1</li>
    <li>Elemento 2</li>
    <li>Elemento 3</li>
    <li>Elemento 4</li>
    <li>Elemento 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Mucha sgracias, si me sirvio, por que mantienes el focus en el input

Comment: @diegoperez97, si te sirvió, no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada para que otros usuarios con problemas similares sepan que puede servirles.

Answer (score 0):

Ya me topé hace tiempo con una duda bastante parecida a la tuya, pero en mi caso era para controlar toda una interfaz a través del navegador de una smart tv, es decir, con mando, y encima por tablas... imagínate las risas.

Lograr esto es relativamente sencillo.

- Primero establece el atributo `tabindex` en 0 a todos los elementos li, sin esto, no es posible enfocarlo.
- Define un id en cada iteración con el valor del índice actual.
- En cada iteración, añade el evento `onkeydown` y que lleve a una función, pero acuérdate de añadir como primer parámetro el evento (para saber qué tecla es la que has presionado), y como segundo, el índice de la iteración.

Hace un tiempo que ya no toco JS vanilla en frontEnd, así que mis conocimientos están un poco oxidados, pero creo que esto te puede orientar de alguna forma:

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li id="1" tabindex="0" onkeydown="switchFocus(event, 1)">Ejemplo 1</li>
    <li id="2" tabindex="0" onkeydown="switchFocus(event, 2)">Ejemplo 2</li>
    <li id="3" tabindex="0" onkeydown="switchFocus(event, 3)">Ejemplo 3</li>
    <li id="4" tabindex="0" onkeydown="switchFocus(event, 4)">Ejemplo 4</li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
li:focus {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
function switchFocus(key, current) {
    if (key.code == "ArrowDown") document.getElementById(current+1).focus();
    else if (key.code == "ArrowUp") document.getElementById(current-1).focus();
    else if (key.code == "Enter") alert(`Seleccionando el elemento ${current}`);
}
```

Por cada evento, JavaScript lo recoge, comprueba la tecla y posteriormente decide a qué elemento debe enfocar (current es el id del elemento actual, por ende, o suma, o resta, y esto da como resultado el enfoque en los elementos hermanos).

Pruébalo todo en JSFiddle, bajo mi punto de vista es un buen punto de partida.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, me sirvio lo de agregar el tabindex=0 en el li, pero solo me desplaza hasta el segundo li de la lista que se genera dependiendo de las coincidencias de lo que escriba y de ahi si lo vuelvo a buscar me selecciona hasta el tercero si hago la misma búsqueda. vere en unos momentos como interactuar mejor con la tecla tab.

Comment: Revisa la consola, tal vez esté lanzando algún error y puedas guiarte con eso. Con el tabulador vas a tener el problema de que según la estructura, el foco se irá a otro elemento, así que este caso lo más lógico sería añadir el índice de la iteración al tabindex, y después si quieres volver a un elemento superior, presionar shift y después tab.