# ¿Cómo mantener el focus en el input cuando se rellena con lo que seleccione de una lista?

Tags: javascript, html, elixir

tengo un input que al escribir palabras clave se renderea una lista con los datos de la base de datos para seleccionarlos y el que seleccione se pase al input (como si fuera un autocompletado) pero quiero que sigua con el focus activo en el input ya que cuando se rellena/autocompleta se pierde el focus, esto para poder seguir dentro del form y presionar la tecla Enter y hacer el submit con el boton. Gracias.

Form:

```
<%= f = form_for :heading, "#", phx_submit: :add_item, phx_change: :set_product, "phx-target": "#stateful-#{@id}", title: "Agregar artículo a la lista" %>
      <div class="input-group ">
        <%= text_input f, :product, autofocus: "true", class: "form-control", id: "InputArticulo", placeholder: "Buscar artículo...", list: "list_items", value: @product, autocomplete: "off", title: "Campo de selección de artículo para agregar a la lista" %>
        <button type="submit" id="BotonAgregar" class="btn btn-success" phx-value="<%= @product %>" phx-disable-with="Agregando..." onclick="">Agregar Producto</button>
        <%= hidden_input f, :item_id, value: @item_id %>
        <%= hidden_input f, :order_id, value: @order_id %>
```

Lista:

```
<ul class="list-group">
      <%= for item <- @items do %>
        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action max-h-48 overflow-auto" tabindex="0" onkeydown="switchFocus(event, 1)" phx-click="select_item" phx-keydown="select_item" phx-value-item="<%= item.id %>" phx-value-name="SKU: <%= item.sku %>, Código: <%= item.value %> - <%= item.name %>">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <div id="itemName" class="flex-1">
              <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> <%= item.name %>
              <p class="mb-0">sku: <%= item.sku %>, código: <%= item.value %></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
```

[image: Input y lista rendereada]

Al seleccionar se pierde el focus dentro del input
[image: Input sin el focus activo]

Comment: en el código que pones no hay javascript, más bien, me parece Ruby

Comment: es HTML/Elixir es parecido a Ruby pero tambien acepta scripts de javascript, crei que la solucion tambien puede ser de esa manera.

Comment: En teoría igual que metes el contenido en el input, puedes situar sobre este el foco en el mismo momento. Si no es así, asignále un *observer* al input, que ponga el foco cuando cambie su contenido https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: En esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/463708/54039) a tu pregunta anterior no se pierde el foco. En todo caso, esta pregunta está incompleta porque falta el código con el que seleccionas el valor y lo asignas al campo.